# Save Sortable list through jquery UI list with ng-click AngularJS - Not saving correct order

Tags: angularjs

I have a sortable jQuery UI list and I am trying to send the data back to the server. When I send the data back to the server I am still getting the original order. However -  when I console.log sortAreasEV, I am getting the correct sort order.

HERE IS THE SORT AREAS

```
$("#sortAreas").on('nestable-stop', function(ev)
   {
       var serialized = $(this).data('nestable').serialize(),
           str = '';
       //console.log( $(this).data('nestable').list() );
        str = iterateList(serialized, 0);
        //iterateList(serialized);

        $("#sortAreasEV").val(str);
    });
});
```

UL CLASS

```
<ul id="sortAreas" class="uk-nestable">
    <li data-item="{{area.label}}" data-item-id="{{area.uuid}}" ng-repeat="area in areas">
     <div class="uk-nestable-item">
         <div class="uk-nestable-handle"></div>
         <div data-nestable-action="toggle"></div>
          <div class="list-white">{{area.label}}</div>  
      </div>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

BUTTTON CLASS

```
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="sortAreasEV" ng-click="saveSort(areas)">
```

SORT AREAS CONTROLLER

```
 $scope.saveSort = function (areas) {
            console.log(areas); 
            $http({
                    method: 'POST', 
                    url: apiUrl,
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization': token
                    },
                    data: {areas:areas}
                })
```

Any help with be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here is a plunker....http://plnkr.co/edit/fnHUFP42mb30yWe9h7T0?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I don't think by changing the order of the elements in that list the original array is being updated. It doesn't *look* like the nestable-stop event is updating that array but there is code not visible from your sample. Check that the array is actually being updated and/or post a link to plunkr.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/fnHUFP42mb30yWe9h7T0?p=preview Here is the working plunker! Thanks for helping :)